# Utterance progress listener doesnot get called even after passing a hash map parameter

Tags: android, speech-recognition, text-to-speech

Here is my code, I have a series of questions that will be asked by TTS and after every question speech recognizer will be invoked.My utterance listener is never being called.

```
   @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_speech_recognizer);
            tts = new TextToSpeech(this /* context */, this /* listener */);
}

//This is called after first time user clicks a button

    private void processEnquiry() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            for(int i=0;i<EnquiryList.size();i++)
            {
                speak(EnquiryList.get(i).toString());

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                initialized = true;
                tts.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
                if (queuedText != null) {
                    speak(queuedText);
                }
            }
        }

        public void speak(String text) {
            // If not yet initialized, queue up the text.
            if (!initialized) {
                queuedText = text;
                return;
            }
            queuedText = null;
            // Before speaking the current text, stop any ongoing speech.
            //tts.stop();
            // Speak the text.
            setTtsListener();
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID,"MessageId");
            tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, map);
        }
    private void setTtsListener()
        {
        final SpeechRecognizer callWithResult = this;

        int listenerResult = tts.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener()
        {
        @Override
        public void onDone(String utteranceId)
        {
        callWithResult.onDone(utteranceId);
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(String utteranceId)
        {
        callWithResult.onError(utteranceId);
        }
        @Override
        public void onStart(String utteranceId)
        {
        callWithResult.onStart(utteranceId);
        }
        });
        if (listenerResult != TextToSpeech.SUCCESS)
        {
        Log.e(TAG, "failed to add utterance progress listener");
        }


        }
         public void onDone(String utteranceId)
         {
             callSpeechRecognition();
         }
         public void onError(String utteranceId)
         {
         }
         public void onStart(String utteranceId)
         {
         }
```

TextToSpeech.SUCCESS returns 0.

Comment: I had a similar problem. I ended up using the deprecated setOnUtteranceCompletedListener() inside onInit() method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a modified version of your script, where the `onDone()` method in the Utterance listener is called. I have eliminated many features that are not directly connected to the TTS playback, to create a barebones sample. If this works for you, then you can add back the other features one by one, testing that nothing breaks on the way.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.SpeechRecognizer;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.speech.tts.UtteranceProgressListener;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {

    private TextToSpeech tts;
    private SpeechRecognizer sr;

    private boolean initialized;
    private String queuedText;
    private String TAG = "TTS";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_speech_recognizer);
        tts = new TextToSpeech(this /* context */, this /* listener */);
        tts.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(mProgressListener);

        sr = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this); // added
    }

    // Modified for testing purposes

    //This is called after first time user clicks a button
    /*
    private void processEnquiry() {
        for (int i = 0; i < EnquiryList.size(); i++) {
            speak(EnquiryList.get(i).toString());
        }

    }
    */

    public void processEnquiry(View v) {
        speak("Process enquiry");
    }
    // End of modification

    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            initialized = true;
            tts.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);

            if (queuedText != null) {
                speak(queuedText);
            }
        }
    }

    public void speak(String text) {
        // If not yet initialized, queue up the text.
        if (!initialized) {
            queuedText = text;
            return;
        }
        queuedText = null;
        // Before speaking the current text, stop any ongoing speech.
        //tts.stop();
        // Speak the text.
        setTtsListener(); // no longer creates a new UtteranceProgressListener each time
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, "MessageId");
        tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, map);
    }

    private void setTtsListener() {
        // Method radically simplified; callWithResult is retained but not used here
        final SpeechRecognizer callWithResult = sr; // was `this`
    }

    private UtteranceProgressListener mProgressListener = new UtteranceProgressListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStart(String utteranceId) {
        } // Do nothing

        @Override
        public void onError(String utteranceId) {
        } // Do nothing.

        @Override
        public void onDone(String utteranceId) {
            callSpeechRecognition();
        }
    };

    private void callSpeechRecognition() {
        Log.d(TAG, "callSpeechRecognition() called");
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly and not sure if this answer will help you, but I think you should not set UtteranceProgressListener every time you request TTS to speak, instead you should set the listener at onInit() once.
And note that the empty text will not be spoken so no callback will be invoked as well.

Though basically setting the listener after TTS initialization looks fine for me and works without problems on my Nexus5 and GalaxyS4, even if setting the listener every time I request TTS to speak, so there might be some device specific problems or some TTS engine specific problems.

Oops I forgot to mention that UtteranceProgressListener is available on API level 15 and above, so the listener will no be invoked on API level 14 and below.